# GitHub Markdown - double brackets

Tags: github, wiki, markdown

I've been trying to find some documentation on how to do this, but I can't seem to find anything similar. I'm trying to add double brackets to a code block in GitHub MD:

```
[[something]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the following seem to work:

Inline:

```
this is some `[[code]]`
```

Block with spaces:

```
    this is some [[code]]
```